# MapReduce with MongoDB - how many times does reduce run?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm using MapReduce in MongoDB, and I think I've wrapped my head around all of it, except one piece I still don't understand: how many times does `reduce` run?

For example, I have a collection of "items," each with a "category". This is the test data (written in javascript, for a node.js unit test):

```
var i = 0;
var dummyCategories = [
  { categoryId:(++i), categoryName:'Category '+i },   // [0] 1
  { categoryId:(++i), categoryName:'Category '+i },   // [1] 2
  { categoryId:(++i), categoryName:'Category '+i },   // [2] 3
  { categoryId:(++i), categoryName:'Category '+i },   // [3] 4
  { categoryId:(++i), categoryName:'Category '+i }    // [4] 5
];

i=0;
var dummyItems = [
  { itemId: 'TestItem' + (++i), title: 'Test Item ' + i,      // [0] 1
    category: dummyCategories[0]
  },
  { itemId: 'TestItem' + (++i), title: 'Test Item ' + i,      // [1] 2
    category: dummyCategories[1]
  },
  { itemId: 'TestItem' + (++i), title: 'Test Item ' + i,      // [2] 3
    category: dummyCategories[2] 
  },
  { itemId: 'TestItem' + (++i), title: 'Test Item ' + i,      // [3] 4
    category: dummyCategories[3]
  },
  { itemId: 'TestItem' + (++i), title: 'Test Item ' + i,      // [4] 5
    category: dummyCategories[4]
  },
  { itemId: 'TestItem' + (++i), title: 'Test Item ' + i,      // [5] 6
    category: dummyCategories[0]
  }
];
```

There are 6 items, 5 categories, one of the categories appearing twice and the rest once.

In my `map` function, I'm emitting `(this.category.categoryId, { items: 1 });`. (The full version of this includes other metrics in the value object besides # of items, but this behavior is the same either way.)

My `reduce` function looks like this:

```
function reduce(key, values) {
  var totals = {
    items: 0
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    totals.items += values[i].items;
  }

  return totals;
};
```

(The output structure is the same in map as in reduce, as it needs to be.)

So I run this through mapReduce with `verbose=true`, and it shows these stats:

counts: { output: 5, emit: 6, reduce: 1, input: 6 }

input:6 makes sense, there are 6 documents.
emit:6 makes sense, it emitted 1 category per document.
output:5 makes sense, there are 5 categories.
But why did reduce run only once?

Writing this out now, it seems to be running reduce for each emitted key that appears more than once. So when a key is only emitted once, it doesn't reduce it. Is that correct? What would be the mathematical formula for determining how many times reduce runs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in that reduce doesn't run if the key is only emitted once. I don't think a mathematical formula exists that will tell you how many times reduce is going to run.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is necessary. For big data set individual reduce invocations will be split between nodes and run at the same time.  Size of individual reduce job chunks will vary depending on configuration - documentation says that individual emits can not be more than 
half of maximal document size so I think it implies that maximal reduce batch will be of maximal document size.